# Xamarin iOS searchbar customization

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do the following customization of the Xamarin searchbar for iOS;

- Change the X (close) icon in the search bar that appears when search text is added
- Add padding between the search text and the search icon

I have added a custom Renderer with the code as follows;

```
public class ExtendedSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        UITextField txSearchField = (UITextField)Control.ValueForKey(new Foundation.NSString("searchField"));
        txSearchField.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#f0f3f7").ToUIColor();
        txSearchField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        txSearchField.Layer.CornerRadius = 6f;
    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SearchBar.Text))
        {
            Control.SetShowsCancelButton(false, false);
        }
    }
}
```

How this code be extended to allow the above customization?

Comment: In which way do you want to change the close icon?

Comment: To change it with a new icon image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOS UiTextField has [ClearButtonMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uitextfield.clearbuttonmode?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), first can set like this:

```
uITextfield.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
```

If want to change image of cancle button ,need to use Delegate of textfield:

```
uITextfield.Delegate = new TextFieldDelegate();
```

**TextFieldDelegate.cs**

```
public class TextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
{
    public override bool ShouldChangeCharacters(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
    {
        UIButton button = (UIButton)textField.ValueForKey(new Foundation.NSString("_clearButton"));

        if (button is UIButton)
        {
            button.SetImage(new UIImage("eye.png"), UIControlState.Normal);

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The effect as follow:

[image]
[image]